# Cloudformation giving error "Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]"

Tags: .net, jenkins, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, continuous-deployment

I am trying to implement Continuous Deployment for my .net core app. When lambda function is invoked, I'am trying to create a cloudformation to spin up the resources. But getting error:

Creating Cloud Formation stack: gateway-api-uat-stack
Failed to create stack: gateway-api-uat-stack. Reason: Detailed Message: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND] (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InsufficientCapabilitiesException; Request ID: 4779587c-2a17-11e9-a093-c1704a1bf953)
Status Code: 400
Error Code: InsufficientCapabilitiesException

Deleting Cloud Formation stack: gateway-api-uat-stack
Cloud Formation stack: gateway-api-uat-stack deleted successfully
Finished: FAILURE

This is my serverless.template file

```
"AspNetCoreFunction" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Handler": "Handler-name",
    "Runtime": "dotnetcore2.0",
    "CodeUri": "",
    "MemorySize": 512,
    "Timeout": 300,
    "Role": null,
    "Policies": [ "AWSLambdaFullAccess" ],
    "Environment" : {
      "Variables" : {
      }
    },
    "Events": {
      "ProxyResource": {
        "Type": "Api",
        "Properties": {
          "Path": "/{proxy+}",
          "Method": "ANY"
        }
      },
          "RootResource": {
        "Type": "Api",
        "Properties": {
          "Path": "/",
          "Method": "ANY"
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

When using the `Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31`, [Cloudformation requires](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStackSet.html) the `CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND`.

If you're deploying from the command line, add `--capabilities CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND` to your create / deploy command.

Comment: I am using AWS Lambda Plugin

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that is.