# (InsufficientCapabilitiesException): Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Based on a local AWS Cloud Formation `.yaml` file. I'm running the following command

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name someTest --template-body file://template.yaml
```

throwing the following error

```
An error occurred (InsufficientCapabilitiesException) when calling the CreateStack operation: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]
```

I've read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html) that this is related to the fact that the template contains `macros`. In this case, inside the `.yaml` file, it calls the `AWS::Serverless::Function`, that is,

```
Resources:
  ResourceName:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    ...
    ...
```

What are the options for resolving this issue when creating a stack?

Comment: [Cloudformation giving error "Requires capabilities : \[CAPABILITY\_AUTO\_EXPAND\]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555691/cloudformation-giving-error-requires-capabilities-capability-auto-expand)

Answer (score 5):

### Solution:

Just append

```
--capabilities CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
```

to the command

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name someTest --template-body file://template.yaml --capabilities CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
```

### Explanation:

As the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html) states, **macros perform custom processing on templates**, like operations and transformations. In this example, the [AWS::Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-aws-serverless.html) transform "takes a template written in the AWS Serverless Application Model syntax and transforms and expands it into a compliant AWS CloudFormation template".

Thus, when calling the `create-stack` operation on a template that contains macros, it shoud **specify the capability** `CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND`.